# Angular Reactive Forms and Laravel api(many to many sync)

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, api, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on an Laravel API where I need to update 2 models that are connected with a Many to Many relationship(SteeringScope and Feature), also, a property named "value" is stored in the pivot table.
I need to update the relationship between this table and the pivot value. I know that I can use the [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) method to update the pivot table:

```
$steeringscope->features()->sync($request->features);
```

I tested this from PostMan with the following data and it works as expected:

```
{
    "steering_technology": "Test 4243",
    "features": {
        "1": {
            "value": "test"
        },
        "2": {
            "value": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to send this data from and Angular client where I use reactive forms to build this structure.

I started to create the form using nested form groups:

```
createSteeringForm(): void {
    this.steeringFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      steeringTechnology: [this.scopes.steeringScope.steeringTechnology, []],

      features: this.formBuilder.group(this.getScopeFeatures(this.scopes.steeringScope.features))
    });
  }
```

Using "**this.steeringFormGroup.value**" will generate the same structure like I use from postman and it will update the data correctly. But the the feature list is dynamic and I need to use *ngFor in order to display it.

My ideea is to use [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) and I changed the code to:

```
createSteeringForm(): void {
    this.steeringFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      steeringTechnology: [this.scopes.steeringScope.steeringTechnology, []],
    
      features: this.formBuilder.array(this.getScopeFeatures(this.scopes.steeringScope.features))
    });
  }

  getScopeFeatures(features: IFeature[]) {
    const featureGroups = [];
    for (const feature of features) {
      const group = new FormGroup({
        [feature.id]: new FormGroup({ value: new FormControl(feature.value), })
      });
      featureGroups.push(group);
    }

    return featureGroups;
  }
```

But when I get the form value like this:

```
{
    "steeringTechnology": "Test 4243",
    "features": [
        {
            "1": {
                "value": "test"
            }
        },
        {
            "2": {
                "value": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideea how to structure the form array in a way that the form value will be like this:

```
{
        "steering_technology": "Test 4243",
        "features": {
            "1": {
                "value": "test"
            },
            "2": {
                "value": "test"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you iterate thIs object formgroup inside html then ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, I plan to use Form array: https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a